# Android disable webview scroll but not inner scrollview

Tags: android, scroll, webview

In my android app, I have one webview, and when loading a website, I want to disable the scroll of the webview, but not the inner scroller in the website it self.

For example,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
I want to disable the most outside scroller since my browser is small, but I want to keep the scroller in questions list still working.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is my answer, and I think it is stupid to have this solution... But client's requirements, I wish no one will use it forever...

```
public class NoScrollWebView extends WebView implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener  {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private WebViewActionListener mWebViewActionListener;


public NoScrollWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initUI();
}

public NoScrollWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initUI();
}

public NoScrollWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initUI();
}


private void initUI(){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), this);
    setOnTouchListener(webviewOnTouchLIstener);
    initialWebViewSettings();
}

private void initialWebViewSettings() {

    WebSettings webSettings = getSettings();
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(false);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt)
{
    super.onScrollChanged(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this.scrollTo(0,0);
}


private View.OnTouchListener webviewOnTouchLIstener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Avoid multipe touch point
        if(event.getPointerCount() > 1){
            return true;
        }

        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            // single tap
            return true;
        }else {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    return false;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return false;
                }
                default:
                    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            }
        }
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.e("SFD", "m_downX onDown");
    scrollTo(0, 0);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.e("SFD", "m_downX onSingleTapUp");
    scrollTo(0, 0);
    if(mWebViewActionListener != null) {
        mWebViewActionListener.onTapped();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Log.e("SFD", "m_downX onScroll");
    scrollTo(0, 0);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.e("SFD", "m_downX onLongPress");

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.e("SFD", "m_downX onFling");
    scrollTo(0, 0);
    return true;
}


public interface WebViewActionListener {
    void onTapped();
}

public void setWebViewActionListener(WebViewActionListener listener){
    this.mWebViewActionListener = listener;
}
```

Comment: "I wish no one will use it forever..." Don't be so sure ;) Thanks!